# Magento 2 How to retrieve all select attribute labels ids and/or names

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-attributes

Example "developer" attribute of the type select contains

```
 ID - LABEL
 12 - junior
 13 - regular
 14 - senior
```

How to retrieve all labels ids and/or names for this attribute. I need something like that

```
$attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get($attributeCode); //load select attribute

$labelsNames = $attribute->getLabelNames();
$labelsIds = $attribute->getLabelsIds();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$attributeOptions = $this->attributeRepository->get($attributeCode)->getOptions();
$idsLabels = array();
foreach($attributeOptions as $attributeOption){
    $idsLabels[$attributeOption->getValue()] = $attributeOption->getLabel();
}
```